# XSD two xs:sequence with same first element inside xs:choice error

Tags: xml, xsd

I have written a simple xsd file like this

```
<xs:element name="Cell">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:choice>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element ref="RF"/>
    <xs:element ref="BCCH"/>
    <xs:element ref="CarrierMeas"/>
  </xs:sequence>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element ref="RF"/>          
  </xs:sequence>
  </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

and when I use xml tools in notepad++ to validate a xml file , it shows that

> "Unable to parse schema file,local complex type:The content model is
>   not determinist!"

I have found that if two sequence with same first element,this error will occurs,and if I replace any "RF" in the XSD to other names,it will work Ok.I have found no reference document about this,would you please kindly help me to tell me why?Thank you very much!

Comment: It's called the Unique Particle Attribution (or UPA) constraint. Knowing what it's called, you will find plenty of information about it.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, it is a requirement for parser not to have to "look forward" in the document to determine which is the applied content model (should it be a DTD or a schema). This is also known as the "[*unique particle violation*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=unique%20particle%20violation)".

For a reference, you can have a look at http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#determinism.

Anyway, your content model can easily be rewritten like so, without needing to rename any element:

```
<xs:element name="Cell">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="RF" />
                <xs:sequence minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:element ref="BCCH"/>
                    <xs:element ref="CarrierMeas"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

The allowed sequences of elements are exactly the ones you would like to achieve in the schema you posted. (Note, however, that it sometimes may not be possible to rework an XSD into a non-ambiguous form.)